# using Pipes create N child and send message to parent

Tags: c, linux, random, pipe

I'm trying to create n child with the same parent, and send the random number from child -> parent.
For now, I have a problem to send random 0/1 from child -> parent.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<unistd.h> 
#include<sys/types.h> 
#include<string.h> 
#include<sys/wait.h> 

int main() 
{ 
pid_t pids[10];
int i;
int n = 10;

/* Start children. */
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
     if ((pids[i] = fork()) < 0) {
     perror("fork");
         abort();
  } else if (pids[i] == 0) {
   // printf("I am a child with id %d and my parent %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
    int random = rand() % 2;
    printf("\nChild send random: %d\n",random);
    write(pids[1], &random, sizeof(random));    
    exit(0);
    }
   else{
    int ran;
    read(pids[0], &ran, sizeof(ran)); // read from child
    printf("\nParent Received: %d\n", ran);
    }
  
}

wait(NULL);

 }
```

Comment: The first argument of `read()` is a filedescriptor, not a pid.

Comment: You did not create any pipe. Your array `pids` contains the PIDs (process IDs)  not file descriptors. Maybe you can get some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18242731/10622916

Answer (score 0):

The problems are:

first, read and write don't want a pid like first argument but a file descriptor and second, for passing something between two processes you should use a IPC mechanism like pipes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>   
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
    
    int main()
    {
      pid_t pids[10];
      int _pipe[2];
      int i;
      int n = 10;
      int random;
    
      srand(time(NULL));
    
      /* Start children. */
      for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        //printf("%d\n",i);
        pipe(_pipe);
        if ((pids[i] = fork()) < 0) {
          perror("fork");
          abort();
        } else if (pids[i] == 0) { // Child
          random = rand() % 2;
          char str[2];
          sprintf(str,"%d",random);
          //printf("\nChild send random: %d\n",random);
          close(_pipe[0]);
          write(_pipe[1], str, sizeof(str));
          printf("Pipe sended: %s\n",str);
          exit(0);
        }
        else{ // Parent
          char string[1];
          close(_pipe[1]);
          read(_pipe[0],string,sizeof(string)); // read from child
          printf("pipe received: %s\n",string);
          //printf("\nParent Received: %d\n", ran);
        }
    
      }
    
      wait(NULL);
    
    }
```